# React. Как перерендерить компонент, изменяя состояние в родителе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, state

Я делаю приложение со списками задач.
Есть меню со "списками", они хранятся в стейте у родителя (App). Когда я из дочернего элемента удаляю "список" через кнопку - стейт меняется, а кнопка со списком остается на месте, т.е. перерендер не происходит.

Требуется:
При нажатии на кнопку-крестик "список" должен удаляться как из стейта, так и с экрана. Как можно реализовать данный функционал?

[image: Родительский App]

[image: Дочерний Menu с кнопками "списков"]

[image: Кнопки, которые должны удаляться при нажатии на крестик]

Comment: У вас очень простой пример, потому вместо картинок вставьте сюда пожалуйста ваш код по этой [инструкции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const deleteFolderHandler = (folderId) => {
    const folderFiltered = folders.filter(el => el.id !== folderId);
    setFolders(folderFiltered);
}
```

Если я правильно понял задачу конечно. Использую **deleteFolderHandler** вместо **deleteFolder**

p.s хук useCallback не забывай использовать

Comment: И почему же нужен `useCallback` тут?